# Getting the String Value to proceed to the next (specific) Activity

Tags: java, android, string, recommendation-engine

What I am trying here is, I want to get the string value of **flevel** and then when I click the search button it will proceed to the next (specific) Activity.

Goal is:

- if the **flevel** is "Beginner" the next activity will be for the "Beginner", and if the **flevel** is "Experienced" the next activity will be for the "Experienced", and so on..

***flevelfb** = FilipinoBeginner*

```
Bundle bnfb2 = getIntent().getExtras();
    String flevelfb = bnfb2.getString("flevel");
    flevel.setText(String.valueOf(flevelfb));
```

***flevelfe** = FilipinoExperienced*

```
Bundle bnfe2 = getIntent().getExtras();
    String flevelfe = bnfe2.getString("flevel");
    flevel.setText(String.valueOf(flevelfe));
```

*This part is for the search button:*

```
search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String flevels = flevel.getText().toString();


            if (flevels.equals(flevelfb)){
                Intent intent= new  Intent(getApplicationContext(), FilipinoBeginner.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            else if (flevels.equals(flevelfe)){
                Intent intent= new  Intent(getApplicationContext(), FilipinoExperienced.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
```

[image: Main Activity page]

Comment: I wonder, why do you need 2 different bundles and two different strings to store the same data from the same key! Can't you just use `String flevel = getIntent().getExtras()getString("flevel")` and then use a simple `if-else` statement?

Comment: Hi @philoopher97 i did your instruction, but I think my only problem now is the condition inside my if/else statement. Here is what I'm trying right now but still doesnt work...

Comment: @philoopher97 

                if (flevels.equals("Beginner")){
                    Intent intent= new  Intent(getApplicationContext(), FilipinoBeginner.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
                else if (flevels.equals("Experienced")){
                    Intent intent= new  Intent(getApplicationContext(), FilipinoExperienced.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

Answer (score 0):

you can change just search button click like this

```
search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String flevels = flevel.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = null;
            if (flevels.equals("Beginner")){
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FilipinoBeginner.class);
                }
            else if (flevels.equals("Experienced")){
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FilipinoExperienced.class);
            }
           startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```